# Erlang exited with reason - undef (with string:find/2 func)

Tags: erlang

trying to use function `string:find/2`but every time getting the error

```
CRASH REPORT Process <0.779.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{undef,[{string,find,[[<<208,162,51,32,208,190,208,177,209,137,46,44,32,84,51,32,116,111,116,97,108,44>>],[<<208,186,209,128,208,190,208,178>>]],[]},{proxy_layer_cli_handle_req,do_execute_keysearch,4,[{file,\"/opt/proxy_layer/_build/test/lib/proxy_layer/src/proxy_layer_cli_handle_req.erl\"},{line,222}]},{proxy_layer_cli_handle_req,keysearch,3,[{file,\"/opt/proxy_layer/_build/test/lib/proxy_layer/src/proxy_layer_cli_handle_req.erl\"},{line,...}]},...]},...}
```

when i use it in terminal - everything is okay

```
1> string:find(<<208,162,51,32,208,190,208,177,209,137,46,44,32,84,51,32,116,111,116,97,108,44>>,<<208,186,209,128,208,190,208,178>>).     
1> nomatch
```

I'm using Erlang 20.1

here is the code which I use:

```
do_execute_keysearch([First|Rest], PriceList, Keyword, Acc) ->
  Id = utils:get_value(<<"Id">>, First),
  case utils:get_value(<<"Keywords">>, First) of
    <<>> -> do_execute_keysearch(Rest, PriceList, Keyword, Acc);
    undefined -> do_execute_keysearch(Rest, PriceList, Keyword, Acc);
    Keys ->
      case string:find(Keys, Keyword) of
        nomatch ->
          do_execute_keysearch(Rest, PriceList, Keyword, Acc);
        _ ->
          Price = find_price_by_service_id(PriceList, Id),
          NewAcc = [lists:append(Price, First) | Acc],
          do_execute_keysearch(Rest, PriceList, Keyword, NewAcc)
      end
    end;
```

UPDATE:
Issue fixed after changing Erlang version in docker container. (Changed to Erlang 20.1)
Don’t know why there are some modules undefined in Erlang 19

So the problem solved now

Comment: please, provide full example for reproducing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string:find/2` [was added to Erlang in version 20](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/2c72e662bad11a41839780f86680d4bb05367c78) which is why you were getting an `undef` error in Erlang 19. The solution is to upgrade to Erlang 20 (which you've already done).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -2):

Look at the error more carefully. Or rather, try to reproduce it. Which of these looks more like your error?

```
1> catch lists:nonexist(<<1>>, <<2>>).
{'EXIT',{undef,[{lists,nonexist,[<<1>>,<<2>>],[]},
                {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,674}]},
                {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,431}]},
                {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,687}]},
                {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,642}]},
                {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,627}]}]}}
2> catch lists:nonexist([<<1>>], [<<2>>]).
{'EXIT',{undef,[{lists,nonexist,[[<<1>>],[<<2>>]],[]},
                {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,674}]},
                {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,431}]},
                {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,687}]},
                {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,642}]},
                {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,627}]}]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Found the issue! I’m using docker and there is erlang 19vsn. Don’t know why it doesn’t have some of Erlang modules. Changed version to 20.1 and error gone.